# Accessing Map values in gsp page Grails using variables as key

Tags: grails, gsp

I am trying to create multiple divs on the fly using a template which is called for a number of times and each time i create a new div ... which seems to be working fine below is the code. I am passing a map tempMap from the controller to the gsp page which is of the below format

```
         tempMap = [key_1:v1,key_2:v2,key_3:v3] //from the controller

         //this is the gsp part
        <g:set var="counter" value="${1}" />
        <g:while test="${counter <= tempMap.counter}">
        <g:render template="travelDetailsToShow" />
        <g:set var="counter" value="${counter + 1}" />
        </g:while>
```

I need to set the ids of the elements based on the counter which also is working ... But i am unable to set the values of the fields.

```
                <div class="col-sm-6" id="key_${counter}"> // This sets the id to key_1, key_2 depending on the counter value
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Departure Date</label>
                        <span class="input-icon-right input-group">
                            <g:set var="temp" value="kep_${counter}" />
                            **<input type="text" name="key_${counter}" class="form-control" value="${tempMap?.key_${counter}}" readonly></input> // this does not work** 
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></span>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

I searched a lot but with no luck ... can anyone tell me where am i going wrong with this .. Any help is appreciated ... Thanks in advance people

Answer (score 0):

The render tag has a model attribute. It works like the model passed from controller to view. You can use it to pass data into the template.

### view

```
<g:each in="${1..tempMap.counter}" var="counter">
    <g:set var="key" value="key_${counter}">
    <g:render template="travelDetailsToShow" model="${[id: key, value: tempMap[key]]}"/>
</g:each>
```

### template

```
<div class="col-sm-6" id="${id}">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Departure Date</label>
        <span class="input-icon-right input-group">
        <input type="text" name="${id}" class="form-control" value="${value}" readonly></input>
         <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></span>
                        </span>
     </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Emmanuel for your answer ... but i think i wasnt clear enough and misled you to think that the "key" would be static ... As your logic would expect the static value "key" ..... The proper structure of the map is below ...

```
       tempMap = [key_1:v1,anotherkey_1:v2,yetanotherkey_1:v3,key_2:v4,anotherkey_2:v5,yetanotherkey_2:v6]
```

I havent tried out the solution posted by you but got another solution to work.... code for which is below ...

```
                <div class="col-sm-6" id="key_${counter}">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Departure Date</label>
                        <span class="input-icon-right input-group">
                            <input type="text" name="key_${counter}" class="form-control" value='${tempMap?."${'key_' + counter}"}' readonly></input>
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></span>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6" id="anotherkey_${counter}">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Return Date</label>
                        <span class="input-icon-right input-group">
                            <input type="text" name="anotherkey_${counter}" class="form-control" value='${tempMap?."${'another_' + counter}"}' readonly></input>
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></span>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

The problem was that i was not referencing the value in the Map properly... The code that fails is stated below.

```
                                <div class="col-sm-6" id="departureDate_${counter}">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Departure Date</label>
                        <span class="input-icon-right input-group">
                            **<input type="text" name="departureDate_${counter}" class="form-control" value="${tempMap?.${departureDate_counter}"} readonly></input>** // THIS CODE DOES NOT WORK. This will look for a key ${departureDate_counter} and will through a gsp error that tags have not been closed
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></span>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Although i have found a solution to my problem it would be nice if we posted more solutions as i feel that not a lot of solutions are present on the net for grails and gsp ...